# Improving file system performance on emulated Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, kernel, emulation, qemu

I am emulating a Raspberry Pi 3B running the latest Raspberry Pi OS Lite on `qemu-system-arch64` but the file I/O speed is woefully slow.

This is my QEMU command, for starting my virtual machine.

```shell
sudo qemu-system-aarch64 \
-m 1024 \
-M raspi3b \
-kernel kernel8.img \
-dtb bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb \
-sd 2022-09-22-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite.img \
-append "console=ttyAMA0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootwait rootfstype=ext4" \
-nographic \
-device usb-net,netdev=net0 \
-netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22
```

#### Host

```shell
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=speetest bs=1M count=100
100+0 records in
100+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB, 100 MiB) copied, 0.057461 s, 1.8 GB/s
```

#### QEMU

```shell
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=speetest bs=1M count=100
100+0 records in
100+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB, 100 MiB) copied, 8.6373 s, 12.1 MB/s
```

On my host I get about 60mbps when downloading a large file, inside this QEMU machine my download speed peaks at about 100kbps.

What changes can I make to improve the file system performance/download speed.

Comment: Same drama here `104857600 bytes (105 MB, 100 MiB) copied, 39.1871 s, 2.7 MB/s` did you manage to resolve?

Comment: Any luck @jshbrntt? I've been looking into this as well, but not found a better confirguration with the `raspi3b` machine type.